# How is a room structurally suspended above a garage cutout?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structures, building-design, masonry

[image]

The garage of this cavity wall (outer brick layer wall, inner concrete load bearing wall) new build uk house is a cutout directly below a room. i'm confused because this obviously interrupts the masonry, how will the beams of the room be suspended on masonry which has no foundation? How will suspended masonry support itself, does the masonry extend to the roof of the garage, what is the anatomy of this structure?[image]

Comment: The precast steel-reinforced concrete lintels are clearly visibile in both photographs.

Comment: Do a search on lintels.

Comment: thanks. is there concrete masonry on the roof of the garage or is it just a board ceiling beneath the floor joists